# When possession ends, does the victim automatically detect you if you're in their FOV?

Tags: dishonored

I was going for ghost in a level, and had no way across a courtyard.  I ended up possessing one of the guards as he was going past, then going towards the door.  The possession ended just shy of the door, with me in front of the victim, but I didn't hear the chime for being detected, so quickly opened the door to the new area.  At the end of the mission, it showed I'd been detected once, but I didn't think anyone else had detected me.

**When possession ends, does the victim automatically detect you if you're in their FOV?**

Comment: They get 'nauseous', briefly, apparently.

Comment: I always appear at the back of the NPC I possessed, after a possession. Are you sure you appeared in front of the victim?

Comment: @galacticninja - yes, I was facing the door, and the only thing in front of me was the door.  I was thinking that I'd choke him out when I got to the door, but not seeing him, I raced for the door instead.  I'd never actually stayed in a victim until it wore off before, so I thought that might be the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you leave the body of the possessed enemy, you'll be (as some comments pointed out) behind him.

And he'll be nauseating for 5 to 10 seconds. If you step in front of him, he still won't notice you while puking. It's like a stun effect to them apparently and while they vomiting you won't be their priority.

Confirmed by the [wiki](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Possession) :

> Furthermore, possession will cause nausea in some targets, which incapacitates and disorients them for a short period after possession ends.

It takes a while to the guard to get things togheter and think about you again (it's the visual transition between puking and the guard getting back up)

If the guard, by the time you left, was facing you and was standing doing nothing, that's probably where you got spotted. Other than that, they won't see you :)

Comment: As stated in the question, when the possession ended, I was in front of the victim (I could hear him behind me), with only the door in front of me.  That bit from the wiki only confirms that they will be possessed and nauseated.  What I wanted to know was during this time can they still detect you (not to mention why I was in front of rather than behind you).  At this point, I think it was a bug because I was so close to the door- with no way to put him in front of me, it put him behind me.

Comment: my answer comes also from experience and experimenting: first thing i did after upgrading possession to tier 2 was enter a guard's body and exit soon after, just to run around him and see what the effects are. i can confirm you won't get spotted :) not sure if possession time determines how much they stay stunned, tho. i saw characters bending to the floor as well as vomiting as well as just being disoriented for a couple of seconds. a bug can happen, indeed, if the situation is edgy (better seen when using Blink to reach some spots... blink can fail or you may fall even if it seems fine)